# how to add UITapGestureRecognizer to presentViewController and to view

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, presentmodalviewcontroller

I need to dismiss the presentViewController when click the outside the controller, I'm using the following code

```
   UITapGestureRecognizer *tapBehindGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapBehindDetected:)];
  [tapBehindGesture setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
  [tapBehindGesture setCancelsTouchesInView:NO];
  [self.view.window addGestureRecognizer:tapBehindGesture];

- (void)tapBehindDetected:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        CGPoint location = [sender locationInView:nil]; //Passing nil gives us coordinates in the window

        //Then we convert the tap's location into the local view's coordinate system, and test to see if it's in or outside. If outside, dismiss the view.

        if (![self.view pointInside:[self.view convertPoint:location fromView:self.view.window] withEvent:nil])
        {
            // Remove the recognizer first so it's view.window is valid.
            [self.view.window removeGestureRecognizer:sender];
            [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        } 
    }
}
```

its working fine for me, but i had problem in another view. Inside the view controller I add UITapGestureRecognizer to vwHeaderview.

```
     UITapGestureRecognizer *addNewContactsingleFingerTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
        [vwHeaderview addGestureRecognizer:addNewContactsingleFingerTap];

- (void)handleSingleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    //Some code
}
```

If I click the vwHeaderview It call the "tapBehindDetected", I wont call "handleSingleTap".

If I comment above "tapBehindGesture" Its working fine. But I need both to work. any help

Comment: Try to set the GestureRecognizer's delegate and implement this method:
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
    return YES;
}

Comment: Yes, Its working... Thanks @KaszásDávid. But I'm uisng
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {        
    return YES;
}

Answer (score 0):

I add delegate to vwHeaderview and use following function & its working fine for me...

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *addNewContactsingleFingerTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
    addNewContactsingleFingerTap.delegate = self;
    [vwHeaderview addGestureRecognizer:addNewContactsingleFingerTap];

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {        
    return YES;
}
```